# Integrating Date() with MaterialUI Slider Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here's what I am trying to do.

MaterialUI has a Slider Component that can be used with integers. It's my understanding it doesn't allow for decimals or time formats unless it is programmed that way or manipulated in some way.

A normal slider looks like this

[image]

This is done by passing these values

```
<Slider
    min={0}
    max={200}
    step={15}
    value={this.state.fromSlider}
    onChange={this.handleFromSlider}/>
```

The rest of the code is in their docs [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/slider).

What I am trying to accomplish is simple in concept, I want to use to pick a time between (00:00 and 23:59) So that it looks like this

[image]

Here is my code so far.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import Slider from 'material-ui/Slider';

class PlayerNetwork extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const min = new Date();
        const max = new Date();
        min.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        max.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        this.state = {
            min: min,
            max: max,
        };
    }
    state = {
        fromSlider: 0.5,
    };

    handleFromSlider = (event, value) => {
        this.setState({fromSlider: value});
    };

    handleChangeMin = (event, date) => {
        this.setState({
            min: date,
        });
    };

    handleChangeMax = (event, date) => {
        this.setState({
            max: date,
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { min, max } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={4}>
                        <div>From:</div>
                        <div>{this.state.fromSlider}</div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={8}>
                        <Slider
                            min={min}
                            max={max}
                            step={15}
                            value={this.state.fromSlider}
                            onChange={this.handleFromSlider}/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = (PlayerNetwork);
```

Comment: Sliders can only take numerical max/min, or explicit values as shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#A_range_control_with_hash_marks_and_labels . You should use an arbitrary float max and min (like 0 to 24) and convert it to a time when displaying it.

Comment: @AndyRay Based on the depicted example, it would probably be best to set the range from 0 to 1440 to account for minutes in the day.

Comment: @AndyRay I like that idea and I also like the idea of stepping in float, the only problem is integers go from 0-9. Meanwhile minutes go from 0-60. When I change the values for min=0, max=23, step=0.1 I eventually get 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.7, 2.8....etc. Which are not values within a timeframe

Comment: @KenGregory, I'm confused. Where does the 1440 come in, in reference to minutes?

Comment: @LOTUSMS 24 hours in a day, 60 minutes per hour -> 24 * 60 = 1440.  A range of 0-1440 can be transformed to 00:00 (0) - 23:59 (1440)

Comment: @AndyRay thinking further about what you were saying, I imagine I could convert it 0.25 = 00:15, 0.50 = 00:30, 0.75 = 00:45, 1 = 00:60, etc. But woud that work for a time like 11:23 for example and 23:23 respectivily?

Comment: @KenGregory Ah! Got it. I see what you're saying. THat's good.